# VMDK image for Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: 18.04, vmdk

Official Ubuntu 18.04 Server is released in .iso format.
Is it available in in vmdk format anywhere?

If not, I want to create a vmdk image out of official Ubuntu image, can you please guide me in doing the same?

Comment: You can install using the ISO file?

Comment: I wanted an image where I do not need to go through the installation procedure every time I create a new VM. Something like a pre-installed image. I have already tried launching the iso, installing Ubuntu and taking snapshot of the VM using Export to vmdk option in VMWare.
I am not sure if this is the proper way to create a vmdk image, I just wanted to know if there are any official .vmdk images or if there was an official way to convert the iso to vmdk format

Answer (score 1):

You can find the vmdk daily builds (and other formats) in the [ubuntu cloud builds](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/)

[For example, the daily 18.04 is here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/)